# Replacing text inside tags using Jsoup

Tags: java, android, html, parsing, jsoup

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" class="table_border" id="center_table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="25%" class="heading_table_top">S. No.</td>
<td width="45%" class="heading_table_top">
Booking Status (Coach No , Berth No., Quota)
</td>
<td width="30%" class="heading_table_top">
* Current Status (Coach No , Berth No.)
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I scrap a webpage and store the response in a string.

I then parse it into jsoup doc

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(result);
```

Then i select the table using

```
Element table=doc.select("table[id=center_table]").first();
```

Now i need to replace the text in  tag "Booking Status (Coach No , Berth No., Quota)" to "Booking Status" using jsoup.. Could anybody help ?

I tried

```
  table.children().text().replaceAll(RegEx to select the text?????, "Booking Status");
```

Comment: edited my question. please check

Comment: And you also clearly identify what you want to acheive? 'replace text' seems very vague

Answer (score 3):

```
        Elements tds=doc.select("table[id=center_table] td");  // select the tds from your table
        for(Element td : tds) {  // loop through them
            if(td.text().contains("Booking Status")) {  // found the one you want
                td.text("Booking Status");          // Replace with your text
            }
        }
```

then you can use `doc.toString()` to get the text of the HTML back to save to disk, send to a webView or whatever else you want to do with it.

Comment: What do you mean form the table?  If you mean get the HTML back, just do "String newHtml = doc.toString();", and you will have a string with the HTML in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Elements tablecells=doc.select("table tbody tr td");
```

will give you 3 cells.
use a loop to get the each element with

```
Element e=Elements.get(int index);
```

Use the `e.text()` to get the String.

Compare or replace strings with `String.equals() , String.contains(), String.replace()`

Comment: Can you answer my question first, What do you mean by replace? What results are you looking for?

Comment: I want to shorten the text "Booking Status (Coach No , Berth No., Quota)" to "Booking Status" . I dont want to extract the text to a string. I want to use Jsoup replace method to do this

Comment: And your html file is at web server or local disk?

Comment: the Element "table" contains the html of the table.. I want to shorten the text before displaying the table in webview

Comment: the html is response from webrequest.. its temporarily stored in variable.. i am screen scrapping a website

Comment: Sorry I can't make it any more clear. If I do it more 'clear' Ill be writing your program for you. All the methods and classes I already stated in my answer.