# converting HTML to String without TextView

Tags: java, android, html

I am having Problems filling my TextView.
I have an HTML String that needs to be converted from HTML to String and the replace some characters. 
Problem is: I can convert it directly with:
`TextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(sampleText);`

But I need to alter the converted sampleText before giving it to the TextView.

E.g.:

```
String sampleText = "<b>Some Text</b>"
newSampleText = Html.fromHtml(sampleText);
newSampleText.replace(char1, char2);
TextView.setText(newSampletext);
```

Does anyone know how to convert the HTML saved inside the String?

Comment: Perhaps you should just `sampleText.replace(char, char);` before calling `TextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(sampleText))`.

Comment: Yeah, I know, Problem is, that I want to replace <li> with a break. but Html.fromHtml deletes all spans. And Replacing <li> with "\n" before conversion does not work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you don't need formatting, use `Html.fromHtml(sampleText).toString()`

otherwise, you need to extract text from html with [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to find and change text like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14324143/1210841)

Answer (score 0):

please try this one:

You need to use `Html.fromHtml()` to use HTML in your XML Strings. Simply referencing a String with HTML in your layout XML will not work.

[DEMO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview)

Try use [This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.widget.TextView.BufferType%29) version of setText and use SPANNABLE buffer type

[DEMO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235131/set-textview-text-from-html-formatted-string-resource-in-xml)